# Pagination gridview on Datasource from serverside

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am assigning `DataSource` to `GridView` from server side and apply pagination but it doesn't working. I don't know what i am doing wrong Below is my Code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowPaging="true"  OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="10">
</asp:GridView>
```

Below is my Server side code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerId, ContactName, City, Country FROM Customers"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.BindGrid();
}
```

Comment: Did you get exceptions while running the code? Please provide details what things not working properly.

Comment: What is not working? Is it pagination or gridview.

Comment: pagination not showing..while all other thing working fine

Comment: dear all pagination start showing...my query was returning only 5 records while pagination Page Size was set to 10. I change the page size to 2 then it start showing pagination.